# Make changes to app w/o update

Tags: ios, xcode, updates, whatsapp

I was wondering how it works to make changes to an app without re-uploading the binary and go through the whole process again. I have got an example for it:

The developer of *Whatsapp* made changes to his app twice already, just today for the second time. This "update" included the blue indicators which show wether the chat-partner read your message  or not. The 1st time I noticed changes to the app without an update was when he introduced voice messages.

Does anyone have an idea how this works?

Comment: I don't think Whatsapp added such big functionalities without updating the app. It's more likely that the features were added in an older update and then they were enabled remotely (using a remote .plist or a some API call etc.).

Comment: Agree with @DominikHadl.  This is how Uber makes changes to their app or enables special events (ice cream/kittens on demand).  The app already has features built in, hits a server for JSON or some other info, and the app changes based on the contents of the web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Tag Manager to make simple tweaks to your app without having to update the entire app. [Here is an overview](http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2014/09/google-tag-manager-for-ios/) of how it can work (I've used this on Android apps)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your app's interface is supplied in whole or in part from a server - i.e., it's really a web view showing HTML that you are serving. Then you can just change the code on the server.

Comment: Yeah I know but that is not what I was asking for, it actually has nothing to do with the app itself if it only displays a webpage managed by computer.

Comment: But the point is that you don't necessarily _know_ whether the app displays a web page managed by a server, or whether it gets some of its _functionality_ by talking to a server. With something like WhatsApp that is _exactly_ how you should expect the app to work - you _know_ they _do_ have a server that the app talks to all the time.

Comment: Ok that's true but this only refers to the content (the chats) but when talking about positions of buttons and stuff?

Comment: Can you really tell a "button" drawn by the iOS runtime from a "button" drawn by a clever designer and shown in a web view? Remember, back in iOS 2 _all_ iPhone apps were web apps; there was no interface supplied by the iPhone at all. There's a long tradition of this...

Comment: Also, how do you know the interface layout is not coming from the server, even if the interface buttons themselves are iPhone buttons?